# Whats the difference between ぢ and じ?

Tags: grammar, meaning, pronunciation

please also give the pronunciation

Comment: Wikipedia has the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana

Answer (score 2):

These are two different characters with the same pronunciation [/d͡ʑi̞/]

They differ in their origins and in contemporary language the distinction is part of the orthography (much like in any other language, consider "photo" and "foto").

Comment: I think you should have given a bit more information about their origins and where they are used. Also of note is that they are still pronounced differently in some dialects.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm not convinced listing words using one of the two distinct characters in reply to a question what's the difference between them explains anything, so I composed my answer as is. What makes you suggest I *should* do so?

Comment: As for regional differences in pronunciation, there are many almost for every single character. Also not sure, if pointing them out in response to a simple question has any benefit. I think "f" "ph" explains it better, why the two exist in contemporary Japanese.